# Override Shape clicked in Palette action

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

What handler/event do I have to override to change what happens when Shape is clicked in left hand Shapes menu?

I would like to just change style/shape of selected vertex already placed on graph, rather than place new shape on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find it

this is the one:

> Sidebar.prototype.itemClicked = function (cells, ds, evt, elt)